# How do I remove the 'tags' block from a product page?

Tags: xml, layout, magento, php

I'm trying to remove the tagging feature from product pages in my Magento install.

Here are the steps I followed to try to do that:

1. Disabled caching in the Magento admin pages
2. Cleared my browser cache
3. Disabled Tags in the admin pages both for default config and individual stores (Dashboard > System > Config > Advanced > Mage_Tag > Disable > Save was the method I used)
4. Commented out everything in tags.xml

That didn't work the way I expected it to, though. It appears that the tagging *functionality* no longer works, but the "Tags" tab and the form for adding tags are still displayed on product pages.

How can I remove the tagging feature entirely, including the displayed tags and the add-a-tag form?

Comment: Without context "Disabled Tags in the admin" is a meaningless statement.  Describe the steps you took to disable the tags in the admin and people will be better able to help you.

Comment: just updated the question with the requested details

Answer (score 17):

If you are using a local.xml then just use this code:

```
<remove name="product_tag_list" />
```

Using local.xml is the easiest way to modify your page. Also the best way btw. Better then just disabling it via backend. Via xml it doesn't load so in the end performance of your shop is better.

Comment: I can confirm this one worked for me. `<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <remove name="product_tag_list" />
    </default>
</layout>
`

Comment: You must wrap this with  <catalog_product_view> tag like `<catalog_product_view><remove name="product_tag_list" /></catalog_product_view>` , it will remove only from product view page  . You can wrap with default tag for all pages.

Answer (score 8):

Easy one :) Just add following in local.xml (inside layout tags).

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.additional">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>product_tag_list</name></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: thanks Daniel, that didn't work either but it did make me review catalog.xml and I was able to remove the tags tab by commenting out the relevant line within the 'product view' section.

Comment: Which is better, your version or <remove name="product_tag_list" /> ?

Answer (score 2):

which tag.xml did you comment out? The one in your custom theme or the default?  You need to do both, otherwise the default layout simply reinserts the values you omitted.

The `<catalog_product_view>` node in tag.xml is the one you are interested in.

I suggest that you read the article @Alan wrote on [Magento XML Layout](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates) and install the LayoutViewer extension (or buy CommerceBug) to check that the layout updates are not being inserted then report back here if you still have questions.

HTH,
JD

Comment: I commented out everything in tags.xml in the custom theme, default and even the modern theme since it was also there. Basically every tags.xml file I could find. I'll check out the resources you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

1) Copy "tag.xml" file from below location to your custom theme and remove below code.
    app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\tag.xml

```
    <catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Product View</label>
     <!-- Mage_Tag -->
    <reference name="product.info.additional">
        <block type="tag/product_list" name="product_tag_list" before="-" template="tag/list.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.tag.list.list.before" as="list_before" translate="label">
                <label>Tags List Before</label>
                <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

OR
2) To disable tags from admin you need to follow below option.
     Admin: System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced > Disable Modules Output > Mage_Tag = Disable.